# Travar submit de formulário em requisição ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tenho o seguinte código:

```js
jQuery('#modal').on('submit', function(e) {
  jQuery('button[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
  jQuery('div[name="loading"]').html("<i class='fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin'></i> Processando...");
  e.preventDefault();
  setTimeout(function(){ ajax(); }, 10000);
  jQuery('div[name="loading"]').html("");
  jQuery('button[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
});

function ajax() {
  var data = jQuery('#form').serializeArray();
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "url",
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    async: false,
    success: function(returnjson) {
    },
    error: function(returnjson) {
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<span><a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">Alterar informações pessoais</a></span>
<div class="modal" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Alterar Informações pessoais</h4>
      </div>
      <form class="form-horizontal" id="form" action="#">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <input id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" required type="text" class="form-control input-md">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <input id="cep" name="cep" placeholder="Cep" required type="text" class="form-control input-md">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12" name="loading" id="loading"></div>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" id="submit">Salvar alterações</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Preciso que assim que o cliente clicar no botão de enviar, travar o botão `submit` do `form` e aguardar uma resposta do `ajax`.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, eu fiz algumas alterações no seu código. Você gostaria de bloquear o botão e mudar outras coisas certo? Bom eu agrupei a maioria das coisas em um só lugar, mas pode ser usado separadamente também. Assim que o formulário é submetido ele executa um post ajax. Acrescentei o 'beforeSend' que acontence antes do post ser dado, e dentro dela bloqueei o botão e mudei a cor do background, tudo isso com o jQuery, sem precisar de nada muito complicado.

Dê uma olhada, verifica se esse código ajuda, e qualquer dúvida faça um comentário.

```js
jQuery('#modal form').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var form = jQuery(this);
  var btnsubmit = form.find('button[type=submit]');
  var loader = jQuery('#loading');
  
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "url", 
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend : function(){
          //Aqui está o que você quer
          // bloqueia o botão submit
          btnsubmit.prop('disabled', true);
          btnsubmit.css({backgroundColor:'#e2e2e2'});
          loader.html("<i class='fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin'></i> Processando...");
          btnsubmit.addClass("loading");
        },
        success: function(returnjson){
          // desbloqueia o botão submit
          btnsubmit.prop('disabled', false);
          btnsubmit.css({backgroundColor:'black'});
          loader.html('');
          btnsubmit.removeClass("loading");
          
          setTimeout(function(){}, 3000);
        },
        error: function(returnjson) {
          // desbloqueia o botão submit
          btnsubmit.prop('disabled', false);
          btnsubmit.css({backgroundColor:'black'});
          loader.html('');
          btnsubmit.removeClass("loading");
          
            setTimeout(function(){}, 3000);
        }
  });
  // mantém a certeza de que o form não será submetido
  return false;
});
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<span><a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">Alterar informações pessoais</a></span>
<div class="modal" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Alterar Informações pessoais</h4>
      </div>
      <form class="form-horizontal" id="form" action="#">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <input id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" required type="text" class="form-control input-md">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <input id="cep" name="cep" placeholder="Cep" required type="text" class="form-control input-md">
              </div>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <div class="col-md-12" name="loading" id="loading"></div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" id="submit">Salvar alterações</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```